# How do I access SESSIONs in CakePHP's app.php?

Tags: php, session, cakephp, cakephp-3.x, cakephp-3.3

I am using CakePHP 3.3

I am trying to set session timeout's value and other settings in app.php to a value stored in config database table.

I tried using the line below but it's just stoping execution of the webpage.

```
$myConfigs = Cake\View\Helper\SessionHelper::read('my_configs');
```

Can anyone please let me know how do I access session out side controller and model, OR is there a way to set values of the variables in app.php in controller?

Comment: What version of CakePHP?

Comment: Sorry, it's CakePHP 3.3

Comment: It's not clear what you are trying to achieve. If you are referring to the config/app.php file it should be just returning an array that is used to populate the app's config. What is `$myConfigs`?

Comment: I am trying to set session timeout variable's value to a CakePHP session called 'my_config' in config/app.php

Answer (score 1):

You could use [Cake\Core\Configure](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/development/sessions.html) to override and creating new settings.

```
use Cake\Core\Configure;

Configure::write('Session', [
    'defaults' => 'php',
    'cookie' => 'my_app',
    'timeout' => 4320 // 3 days
]);

$timeout = Configure::read('Session.timeout');
```